# Verify if all attribute type xs:ID are present in the XML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I've made an XSD that contains this complex Type "Text" :

```
<xs:complexType name="Text">
  <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID" use="required">
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

In a string, I want to find all the Text nodes that are missing the ID.  Is there a way to validate the XML ?

I can't not use XPath because I have other nodes named Text that doesn't required an Id.  I really need to check with the XSD.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean 'other nodes named Text" - in the same namespace? then how do you plan to tell them apart? Whatever your plan is it can be expressed in XPath

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your xml against the xsd by specifying it on the `XmlReaderSettings`, and simply iterating through the `XmlReader` with `while(reader.Read()) {}`, handling the validation events (on `ValidationEventHandler`). For an example, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3740e0b5(VS.80).aspx).

Note that this will report *all* schema errors, so if you have other problems you'll need to filter it out.